# OpenSSH local port binding for a remote host with jumps

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

I am running OpenSSH_7.6p1 and i have found very convenient the ProxyJump feature (e.g. -J )

Is it possible to bind a port on localhost that is mapped to a remote ssh session accessible with jumps?

For example I would like to:

```
ssh -J user1@jump1,user2@jump2:port2 remote_host@username
```

and then do

```
telnet localhost <specific_port>
```

in order to access to remote_host

Answer (score 3):

The local port forwarding option `-L` in `ssh` should work with jumps. Append the following option

```
-L localhost:<specific_port>:localhost:<specific_port_on_remote_machine>
```

Comment: @radicetrentasei I noticed you unaccepted my answer. Did you find any problem with my solution?